# Where do i provide link to signout.aspx in master page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

My sharepoint site doesn't show the logout button. I guess i need to provide link to the signout.aspx page on the master page. 
If I am using v4.master, then where do i provide link to signout.aspx in the master page

Answer (score 1):

In the v4.master page this is added to the master via the user control:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="Welcome" src="~/_controltemplates/Welcome.ascx" %>
...
<wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
</wssuc:Welcome>
```

Which renders like:

[image: wssuc Welcome control]

The "Sign Out" button itself is defined in the .ascx as:

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="ID_Logout"
             Text="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_logout%>"
             Description="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_logoutdescription%>"
             MenuGroupId="200"
             Sequence="300"
             UseShortId="true"
             />
```

So you can add the standard Welcome control, add this link to the standard Site Actions drop down with the snippet directly above, or create a custom Welcome.ascx.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have one question on the welcome.ascx user control.  Where on the .ascx are we providing link to signout.aspx page ?

Comment: If you find the file in the CONTROLTEMPLATES folder under TEMPLATES in the hive you can open it and find the `SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate` above. If you want to implement a custom menu item, see http://www.synteractiveingenuity.com/wordpress/2012/05/01/adding-custom-site-actions-items-to-my-blog/ which is the same process.